# both program have nearly same code but output is different

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

function myFunction()
{
document.write("Oops! The document disappeared!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code is showing output like below

My First Web Page
Try it

After clicking Try it button I got output like below

Oops! The document disappeared!

In internet i found the reason for disappear is If I execute document.write after the document has finished loading, the entire HTML page will be overwritten.
but my doubt is when document has finished loadind...........i am not gettimg it.
Then I modified the above code like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

function myfunction()
{
document.write("My First JavaScript");
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but the above code is showing output like below

My First Web Page
Try it

After pressing Try it button it is not giving any output.I don't know why these 2 program are working like this.help me..................

Comment: Your second attempt has a lower case 'f' `myfunction` should be `myFunction`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo. 

Comment: Also, avoid using `document.write`.  Prefer `innerHTML`.

Comment: @EthanBrown better yet, DOM manipulation

Comment: `innerHTML` is a form of DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second one is failing because you have a small `f` in `myfunction` and call it with a big `F`

In Chrome, if you open Developer tools ( Cntrl-Shift-J ) and go to the console it will show you the javascript error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the second page is that you are calling a function called myFunction.
But the function that you have is called myfunction, the F is in Uppercase.

so the javascript error is:

Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive. You define

```
myfunction
```

But call

```
myFunction
```

Note the **F**.

Answer (score 0):

In your second function, `myfunction`, `F` should be CAPS or at `onclick=myFunction()` `F` should be small. Check your console window. No output is because of javascript errors